# VM Exception while processing transaction: revert — Transferring ether from EOA to contract account

Tags: web3js, truffle, evm, ethereumj, revert-opcode

### Problem summary

I get the following error whenever I try transferring ether from an EOA(externally owned account) to a contract account in one of my functions as seen below. I am currently using the contract-upgradability pattern. The snippet below is from the **data-contract**

```
function fund (uint value, address sender) external payable {
   ...
    // Transfer value to contract balance
    address payable contractAcct = payable(address(this)); 
    // DAO.transfer(value);
    (bool success,) = contractAcct.call{value: value, gas:4000}("");
    require(success, "Pay to account was not successful");
}
```

The snippet below shows how I call the function above from my **app-contract**

```
function fundAirline() public payable{
  // flightSuretyData is the interface of the data-contract.
    flightSuretyData.fund(msg.value, msg.sender);
}
```

Finally, this is how I call the function from my test cases.

```
// Fund first airline
    await config.flightSuretyApp.fundAirline({from: config.firstAirline, value: web3.utils.toWei('10','ether') });
```

### What I tried

I failed when I first tried using the `address.transfer()` method to transfer the ether over to the contract account. After a couple of articles, I was led to believe that using the `call` method as seen above, is the best way to transfer funds to an account because you get the benefit of checking if the transfer passes or not.

Long story short, I am still stuck in this position. Any guide will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you expect it to send eth, the call to fund() should pass a value, like this: `flightSuretyData.fund{value: msg.value}(msg.value, msg.sender);` and the 'contractAcct' should have a payable fallback or receive method in order to receive it

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and I still get the same error, though your solution is really interesting because I haven't come across any material that suggested it as such. If possible, could you please provide me with resources to research further?

Comment: Sure, check this for instance: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/security-considerations.html?highlight=call%20with%20value#sending-and-receiving-ether

Comment: Thanks a lot Dr.Gorilla, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Nice! Just posted it, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 possible issues:

- `flightSuretyData.fund(msg.value, msg.sender);` I guess this call should send eth (based on the name and the args, you should therefore pass the value to send, like this: `flightSuretyData.fund{value: msg.value}(msg.value, msg.sender);`
- in order for the eth transfer (via `call(..)`) to contractAcct to succeed, it needs to implement a receive() or fallback()

See the solidity docs for more info on managing eth transfers: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/security-considerations.html?highlight=call%20with%20value#sending-and-receiving-ether